# Converting polar coordinates to rectangular coordinates

Tags: math, trigonometry

### Convert angle in degrees to a point

How could I convert an **angle** *(in degrees/radians)* to a **point** (X,Y) a fixed distance away from a center-point.

Like a point rotating around a center-point.

Exactly the **opposite** of `atan2` which computes the angle of the point y/x (in radians).

---

***Note:*** I kept the original title because that's what people who do not understand will be searching by!

Comment: hi,
i have polar cordinates for north pole.
how to convert it to Lat-long?

Comment: @PragneshPatel [Altitude = `r`, Latitude = `180°-θ`, Longitude = `φ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). You may want to multiply the lat and long by `180/π` to convert them to degrees.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let the fixed distance be D, then X = D * cos(A) and Y = D * sin(A), where A is the angle.

Comment: `function pol2rect(r, θ) { return [r * Math.cos(θ), r * Math.sin(θ)]; }`

Answer (score 4):

If center-point (Xcp, Ycp) isn't the origin you also need to add it's coordinates to (X,Y) i.e. X = Xcp + D * cos(A) and Y = Ycp + D * sin(A)

Answer (score 2):

What PolyThinker said.

Also, if you need the distance from the origin, it's `sqrt(x^2 + y^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
t = angle
r = radius (fixed distance)

x = rcost
y = rsint
```